# Why isn't my Jax-RS client object deserializing JSON lists in this HTTP response, even though the object mapper does?

Tags: java, json, jax-rs, deserialization

I'm starting to write a client for a REST API, and I've started with a simple call that returns a relatively simple JSON object: one `resultCode` string, one `message` string, and a list of objects.  When I retrieve the object as a string first, and decode it with `ObjectMapper`, it unmarshals just fine, including the list of objects. However, when I retrieve it using the `Client` object, it retrieves only the string properties, and not the list of objects.  I'd like to model API responses that are more complicated than this, but I don't think it'd be wise until I get past this hurdle.

I have tried using annotations like creating a `setResultItems` method with the `@JsonSetter` annotation.  My initial example used getters and setters, but the example I'm posting uses public fields to save space -- the result is the same.  I've also tried forcing the `Client` object to use the same `ObjectMapper`, by registering a `JacksonJsonProvider` to it.  One thing I've noticed is that the `ObjectMapper` calls the constructor that sets everything up right away, but the `Client` requires a no-args constructor, and sets the properties after creating the object.

Here is the simplest version of the response object class:

```java
class ResponseObject {

    public String resultCode;
    public String message;
    public List<Map<String,String>> resultItems;

    ResponseObject() {
        System.out.println("Blank constructor called");
    }
    ResponseObject(
        @JsonProperty("resultItems") List<Map<String,String>> resultItems, 
        @JsonProperty("message") String message, 
        @JsonProperty("resultCode") String resultCode ) {
        System.out.println("Good constructor called");
        this.resultCode = resultCode;
        this.message = message;
        this.resultItems = resultItems;
    }

    private void print() {
        System.out.println("resultCode: " + resultCode);
        System.out.println("message: " + message);
        System.out.println("resultItems: " + resultItems.toString());
    }
}
```

My test application runs this method in a try-catch:

```java
    private static void doGetVariable() throws IOException {
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

        // hey this means the client should decode it the same way right?
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JacksonJsonProvider provider = new JacksonJsonProvider(mapper);
        client.register(provider);

        System.out.println("Getting string and deserializing it");
        String sresp = client.target(URL)
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .get(String.class);
        System.out.println("string: "+sresp);
        ResponseObject resp1 = mapper.readValue(sresp, ResponseObject.class);
        resp1.print();
        System.out.flush();
        System.out.println("\nGetting object directly from the client");
        ResponseObject resp2 = client.target(URL)
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .get(ResponseObject.class);
        resp2.print();
    }
```

Since these things seem to matter, here are the dependencies in my `pom.xml` file.  I had to add the Jersey ones because if I don't, I get a `ClassNotFoundException` because it can't find `JerseyClientBuilder`.  I think that's a hint but I'm not sure what it means.

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.rx</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-rx-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.25.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
            <version>2.25.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.9</version>
        </dependency>
```

When I run it, here is the output.  You can see the raw JSON in the line that starts with `string:`.  I expect `resultItems` to be the same for both requests, but it is only correct in the first request.  Note that it still sets `resultCode` and `message` in both attempts, so it's doing something at least.

```
Getting string and deserializing it
string: {"resultItems":[{"name":"MAX.PACKETSIZE","value":"64512"}],"message":"OK - the variables were successfully retrieved","resultCode":"0"}
Good constructor called
resultCode: 0
message: OK - the variables were successfully retrieved
resultItems: [{name=MAX.PACKETSIZE, value=64512}]

Getting object directly from the client
Blank constructor called
resultCode: 0
message: OK - the variables were successfully retrieved
resultItems: []
```

Also, I would prefer to get rid of the no-args constructor, so that I can make all the fields `private final` and encapsulate everything properly.

Comment: Remove MOXy and try it.

Comment: Removing `jersey-media-moxy` fixed it.  I thought I had pared the pom.xml down to its minimum before I posted it, but I was wrong.

Still, I wonder what forces were at work here. I can understand why moxy might interfere with things if I left everything to magically integrate itself.  but why did it end up using moxy even when I specified the ObjectMapper in the configuration?

Comment: That version of Jersey defaults to using MOXy unless you either disable MOXy with a configuration property or you register another _Feature_ like the `JacksonFeature`, which comes with the dependency jersey-media-json-jackson. Or just simply remove MOXy.